# Camera just works in Portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, camera, landscape, portrait

My camera looks like this in portrait mode:

[image]

and like that in landscape mode:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. how can I set the previewLayer there in fullscreen in landscape mode?
2. why doesn't the camera rotate when i rotate the device? It stays always in portrait mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your `AVCaptureSession` orientation every time device's orientation is changed.

Add a Notification observer to observe any change in device orientation then set `AVCaptureSession` orientation according to device orientation.

Obj-C:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
-(void) orientationChanged
{
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        [_previewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown];

    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        [_previewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];

    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        [_previewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];

    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        [_previewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
}
```

Swift 2:

Add observer somewhere, for example in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(orientationChanged), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Then:

```
func orientationChanged(){
    let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation

    if deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown {
        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
    }
    else if deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait {
        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
    }
    else if deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft {
        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft
    }
    else if deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight {
        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
    }
}
```

You can also provide any of your code or look at this question which has been asked before it may help.
[AVCaptureSession with multiple orientations issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023518/avcapturesession-with-multiple-orientations-issue)

Comment: Maybe could you edit your comment so it's useful in swift?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the phone's "portrait orientation lock" is turned off. And make sure the app allows landscape orientations in the project settings > general tab.